# In Full Calendar - Google Calendar events show GMT times to people who aren't logged into their Google Account

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar, gcal

When you click on a google calendar event in fullcalendar it displays correctly in the pop-up IF the viewer is logged into their Google Account. But if they aren't logged into their Google Account it displays the time in GMT. I suppose Google stores times in GMT and adjusts them based on the timezone preferences of the viewer. But if the viewer isn't logged in then Google doesn't have anything to go on and displays in GMT instead even if you specify the calendar timezone when you set it up in Google.

Is there a way to force the entries to show in local timezone or in PST?

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sure. The site is: http://ebooks.marinet.info/calendar/  So far I tried adding variations of "&ctz=America/New_York" to each of the google links. I also tried messing with the calendar setting itself in gcal.

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this? I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Nope and it's driving me bananas. I think I've determined that the feeds that work have entries with timestamps and the ones that don't have a timezone/stamp for the entire RSS feed, but not each entry. I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to the OP. The fix for this was on jassie's website ebooks.marinet.info/calendar.

```
        timezoneParam   : "America/Los_Angeles",
```

Add the line above to the options section. I didn't try replacing timezone: "America/Los_Angeles", I just used both lines (same as jassie). And get rid of "ignoreTimezone: false" if you're using it in the options section. It breaks this.